# Eclipse : How can I set plug-ins from lib folder in run configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, eclipse-mars

At first I apologize for my bad English, because I'm not good at speaking English.

I have a Question about Eclipse 4.5 settings. When RCP application runs on Eclipse IDE, the application requires plugins defined in Run Configuration.
But Unfortunately only Target Platform plugins are configurable. I want to set plugins from lib folder, but is it impossible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your Target Platform to contain multiple locations so one of them could be your lib folder.

In the Preferences go to 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform'.

Select your target platform and click 'Edit...'

In the Target Content dialog select 'Add...' to add a new Directory, ... to the target platform.

In the example below I have two locations for target platform contents:

[image: Example target platform]